# Print screen not working

Tags: 18.04, print-screen

I have a very recently installed 18.04.3. During the last 2 days on several occasions ( randomly ), <kbd>prntscrn</kbd>, <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>prntscrn</kbd> and <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>prntscrn</kbd> does not work. I use `Peek` and manage with creating a GIF.

I am puzzled why an almost fresh Ubuntu is behaving like this. Is there any fix for this issue? How can I get rid of it from happening again ? Or how can I make <kbd>prntscrn</kbd> working again once it gets disabled ?

Answer (score 0):

The utility responsible for this functionality is gnome-screenshot.

Run `sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove gnome-screenshot` to remove the package and any other dependant packages that aren't needed.

Then, reboot your system and wait for Ubuntu to automatically repair this package at boot.

After logging in, try the shortcuts again.